# Method is not reading the string I type in to it

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am making a ticket system. If the user is searching for a ticket they type in the name. It is not working when i ask the user to type it in.

If I call the method like this: `G1.displayTicket("John Blogs", LottoTickets);`  it does work!

Displaying a certain ticket:

```
System.out.print("\nDo you wish to search for a particular ticket? ");
String certainTicketQ = in.next();
if(certainTicketQ.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
{
    System.out.print("Name of the person you wish to search for: ");
    String name = in.next();
    G1.displayTicket(name, LottoTickets);   
}
```

The method is:

```
public void displayTicket(String name,Ticket[] LottoTickets)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<LottoTickets.length;i++)
    {
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(LottoTickets[i].getName())){
            System.out.println(LottoTickets[i]);
            break; //Breaks out of loop once ticket is found
        }else break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into creating and posting a valid [mre] with your question. Please read the link to see what this entails. Also, you will want to study and learn Java naming conventions. Methods and variables all should begin with a lower case letter, classes with an upper case letter. Following these conventions will make your code easier for others (us!) and your future self to read and understand.

Comment: Use `in.nextLine()` instead of `in.next()`.

Comment: Yes i have tried both in.nextLine() instead of in.next(). @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: @SeanMcavoy - I've posted the answer. Let me know in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Yes Thank you tried it now and it worked great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the presence of `else break;` which is breaking the loop in the first iteration itself if `LottoTickets[0]` is not equal to `name`. It will return the correct result only when `LottoTickets[0]` is equal to `name`.

```
public void displayTicket(String name,Ticket[] LottoTickets) {
    for(int i = 0; i<LottoTickets.length;i++) {
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(LottoTickets[i].getName())) {
            System.out.println(LottoTickets[i]);
            break; //Breaks out of loop once ticket is found
        }else break;
    }
}
```

Just remove it and your method will work as intended i.e. it should be:

```
public void displayTicket(String name,Ticket[] LottoTickets) {
    for(int i = 0; i<LottoTickets.length;i++) {
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(LottoTickets[i].getName())) {
            System.out.println(LottoTickets[i]);
            break; //Breaks out of loop once ticket is found
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.